# How to change value in html loaded with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Upon clicking a button, I load some extra html in my site, which I keep in a different file. After loading it, I want to make some changes in the loaded html. I currently try to do this as follows:

```
$.when($("#divForInsert").load("/toInsert.html")).done(function(){
    $("#someInput").val("new text in it");
});
```

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
<input type='text'
   size='5'
   id='someInput'
   name='someInput'>
```

I am sure that `#someInput` exists (checked it in `toInsert.html` and with inspect element in the browser) and since I load it using .done(), I suppose it's already loaded when I try to change the val of it. So why does it refuse to be changed?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
I incorrectly said it was a div I tried to change, but it was actually an input field. I added it to the question.

Comment: Try using `$('#someDiv').html('content')`

Comment: @doitmyway - Excuse me, but I mistakenly said it was a div, where it was actually an input field of which I'm trying to change the val. I changed it in my initial question. Would you have any ideas now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#divForInsert").load("/toInsert.html", function() {
    $("#someInput").val("new text in it");
});
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I mistakenly said it was a div, where it was actually an input field. I changed it in my initial question. Would you have any ideas now?

Comment: Awesome! Nailed it! Thanks a million!